# Error map_df across files in a folder using R

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse, purrr

So I have a folder of files each of "almost" identical CSV's. They each look something like:

```
EMP ID  WORK DATE   WORK HOURS   JOB TITLE  MGMT CTR
  002    01/02/2019          8     Janitor        44
  003    01/03/2019         29     Analyst       044
  004    01/02/2019        400      Barber         2
   ...
```

I say almost because some of them have a few extra variables but I only care about two of them.

Using the following code I can theoretically combine and group them together based on `WORK DATE` and `WORK HRS` (the two variables I care about).

```
test <- list.files(path = "path", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map_dfr(read.csv) %>%
  select(WORK.DATE,WORK.HRS) %>% 
  group_by(WORK.DATE) %>%
  summarize(hour_sum = sum(WORK.HRS))
```

I do this and I get an error:

```
Error: Can't combine `..1$JOB.NUM` <double> and `..2$JOB.NUM` <character>.
```

It seems these variables are from one or two odd files. But I have no need for them and I thought the select statement would help...it didn't. I tried with `readr`'s `read_csv`.

```
test <- list.files(path = "path", full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map_dfr(read_csv) %>%
    select(`WORK DATE`,`WORK HRS`) %>% 
  group_by(`WORK DATE`) %>%
    summarize(hour_sum = sum(`WORK HRS`))
```

And get a similar error:

```
Error: Can't combine `MGMT CTR` <double> and `MGMT CTR` <character>.
```

Truly I only care about those two variables, and so long as `WORK DATE` is a character or date and `WORK HRS` is an integer, we are good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue would be that some dataset have columns that doesn't match the type.  An option would be convert to a single type within `map_df` and then change the type

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
list.files(path = "path", full.names = TRUE) %>%
     map_dfr(~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
                  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))) %>% 
     select(`WORK DATE`,`WORK HRS`) %>% 
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     group_by(`WORK DATE` = mdy(`WORK DATE`)) %>%
     summarize(hour_sum = sum(`WORK HRS`)) # assume that "WORK HRS" is numeric
```

Comment: okay that fixed it! But now that i have this df titled "test", how do I have "WORK DATE" as a date formate?

Comment: @JohnThomas is the format in month day year or day month year

Comment: Month day year, so 01/01/2019

Comment: It may be also better to `select` inside the `map_dfr`